# url with .html extension

Tags: url, seo

I just realized that my page is also accessible when there is a .html extension on the url.

The url would be:
http://musikwerkluzern.ch/programm

but http://musikwerkluzern.ch/programm.html works as well but some tags are not being rendered with the html extension attached.

And for some reason the google search results link to the page with .html attached.

[image]

That's bad. How can I prevent this? Is this a `.htaccess` thing?

Comment: After further examination I conclude it must be a server thing because other Craft sites I've made on other servers don't have this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I found the solution If anyone runs into the same issue.
This must be a server problem which I can't solve so there is a [htaccess solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) to remove the .html extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```